# How do I get back the project pane in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I clicked an icon near the top of the screen in Qt Creator and now the project pane has disappeared from the left. How do I get it back?

I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1.

Comment: The icon with 2 door halves (one open) on the bottom - tap on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably clicked `Close`.

You can get it back from `Window -> Show Left Sidebar`. Or the default shortcut `Alt+0`.

If it shows a different pane, you can click the name to select the pane type.

if you lost the pane but not the sidebar, then you can hit the `+` icon of the existing pane to split it and set the new pane type to `Projects`.